# How to send php Select box value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

The following code will output as shown in the attached picture.
[image]

Select the value of the Select box in test16 and press the "test19" button, the value of the Select box you want to modify.I want to make the value delivered to php.
I want to know how to deliver the value of the select box in php and how to receive the value delivered.

```
<?php


    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){               

            $test = 'test';
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            echo "<table id='datatable1' class = table style = 'width: 100%; background-color:#dee2e6'>";
                echo "<thead >";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>No</th>";
                echo "<th>test1</th>";
                echo "<th>test2</th>";
                echo "<th>test3</th>";
                echo "<th>test4</th>";      
                echo "<th>test5</th>"; 
                echo "<th>test6</th>";
                echo "<th>test7</th>";
                echo "<th>test8</th>";                                                      
                echo "<th>test9</th>"; 
                echo "<th>test10</th>";
                echo "<th>test11</th>";
                echo "<th>test12</th>";
                echo "<th>test13</th>";
                echo "<th>test14</th>";
                echo "<th>test15</th>";
                echo "<th>test16</th>";
                echo "<th>test17</th>"; 
                echo "<th>test18</th>";  
                echo "<th>test19</th>";                                           
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</thead>";

                echo "<tbody>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['chart_num'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $row['chart_name'] . "</td>";                                        
                echo "<td>" . $row['visit'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['total_medical_bills']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['total_amount']) . "</td>";   
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['amount_asked']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td  style = 'font-weight: bold'>" .  number_format($row['medical_bills_payment']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td  style = 'font-weight: bold'>" .  number_format($row['personal_liability_amount']) . "</td>";                                                  
                echo "<td  style = 'font-weight: bold'>" .  number_format($row['non_payment']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['insurance_division'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['division'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['cash_amount_received']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['card_amount_received']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td style = 'font-weight: bold'>" .  number_format($row['treatment_fees_difference']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['treatment_fees_check_division'] . "</td>";


                echo "<td><select name='". $test ."'>";
                echo "<option value='". $test ."'>First</option>";
                echo "<option value='". $test ."'>Second</option>";
                echo "<option value='". $test ."'>Third</option>";
                echo "</select></td>";



                echo "<td>" . $row['treatment_fees_check'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['treatment_fees_check_modify'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>";                                          

                    if($row['medical_bills_payment'] == $row['personal_liability_amount'] + $row['non_payment']){ 
                            echo "수정불가";
                    }

                    else{                    
                            echo "<a href='treatment_fees_check_update.php?id=". $row['id'] ." title='수정' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='icon ion-edit'></span></a>";
                    }
                echo "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }


                echo "</tbody>";                            
                echo "</table>";

                mysqli_free_result($result);                                  
            } 


        }     

    else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql2. " . mysqli_error($link);
    } 

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);   
?>
```

Comment: You need to add some javascript code. There are several methods to do it. 1. in your javascript code, you can build your url like treatment_fees_check_update.php?id=xxx&field16=yyy. 2. You can use form submission. To do this, you can wrap a table with a <form> tag.

Comment: detail explain please

Comment: Use the first answer by @Sandro Benevides.  He writes correct code.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can have a lot of select boxes, you will need give them an ID so we can reference the respective field. Let's add/change your code as below:

```
$rowCount=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";

                ...

                echo "<td><select id='MySelect".$rowCount."' name='". $test ."'>";
                echo "<option value='". $test ."'>First</option>";
                echo "<option value='". $test ."'>Second</option>";
                echo "<option value='". $test ."'>Third</option>";
                echo "</select></td>";

                ...

                echo "<td>";                                          

                if($row['medical_bills_payment'] == $row['personal_liability_amount'] + $row['non_payment']){ 
                            echo "수정불가";
                    }
                    else{                    
                            echo '<a href="javascript:GetMySelectValue(\'MySelect'.$rowCount.'\','.$row['id'].')" title="수정" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="icon ion-edit"></span></a>';
                    }
                echo "</td>";

   $rowCount++;
```

EDIT:  I missed to add $rowCount++; before close while block. Sorry.

At the end of your document, before close body tag you add:

```
<script>
function GetMySelectValue(select,objId){
   document.location.href= "yoursite.com/treatment_fees_check_update.php?id="+objId+"&myselect="+document.getElementById(select).value;
}
</script>
```

In treatment_fees_check_update.php you get id and select value:

```
$rowid=$_GET['id'];
$myselect=$_GET['myselect'];
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Check if select tag's ID and id string in "javascript:GetMySelectValue(xxxx, uuu)" are same.

Comment: I missed to add $rowCount++; before close while block. Sorry. I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The principles for what you need is to asign a id to each one of the options in the dropdown, so you can send the id of tha specific value, compare with that same id in the database if exists then you will have the column with the value that you need to modify in the database, but first bring and add the proper id of each one of the options in the select.